# Why do I get "ReferenceError: exports is not defined" when using TypeScript and es5?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm attempting to convert an AngularJS app to use TypeScript. However, my compiled JS gives me the following error:

> ReferenceError: exports is not defined

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./built",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5"
},
"include": [
    "components/**/*",
    "factories/**/*"
]
}
```

**header.component.ts:**

```
import angular from "angular";

angular.module("playerEvaluator", ["ui.router", "ngMaterial"])
.component('headerComponent',
{ 
    templateUrl: "templates/header.tmpl.html",
    controllerAs: "$ctrl",
    bindings: {},
    controller: function ($scope, $state, $rootScope) {    
        //Pages
        this.pages = [
            {
                name: "Teams",
                state: "teams"
            }
        ];        
        //Go to selected page
        this.goToPage = (state: string) => {
            $state.go(state)
        }
    }
});
```

It's this line that is throwing the error in **header.component.js:**

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you configured a module loader?

Comment: No, I haven't. Will that fix my problem?

Comment: Yes. If you are using `commonjs` modules, which is the default when you target `es5`, then you need to use a module loader such as `webpack`, because web browsers do not natively support `commonjs` modules. Alternatively, you can use a different module system than `commonjs`.